# How to interpret the gradient norms in convolution neural networks?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, pytorch

It might be basic thing, but I am unable to understand the interpretation of computing the gradient norms.

For example, I am working on binary segmentation using architecture by stacking multiple U-Nets with each net has encoder similar to Resnet34. I trained this network and I obtain the gradient mean and norm values as below:

- > conv1 has mean grad of -1.77767194275e-14
- > conv1 has norm grad of 2.57230658463e-05
- > layer1 has mean grad of 1.27381299952e-11
- > layer1 has norm grad of 0.000390226632589
- > layer2 has mean grad of -2.3107595698e-11
- > layer2 has norm grad of 0.000265486567514

All the values seems to be very low. I am not able to get shall I consider them as vanishing gradient problem or gradients can be really low depending upon the problem.

If the gradients can be really low, what is best way to check for vanishing gradient problem?

Any advice is appreciated to analyze the gradients data. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The low mean values are not problematic. Of course some problem can cause the low values, but the low values don't mean a problem by itself. Moreover I think the norms of gradients are not too low.

We should rethink what causes vanishing gradient problem in this case. When we use ReLU as activation function, gradients don't vanish (but they can be zero).